# Autorunsc64 (sysinternals) command line issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, command-line, sysinternals

I am trying to execute autorunsc64.exe (Sysinternals) in PowerShell like so:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Autoruns\autorunsc64.exe" -a * > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Autoruns\output.txt"`

However, it does not like single or double quotes anywhere. I've tried many variations but cannot seem to find the solution. I keep getting the following errors:

`Unexpected token '-accepteula' in expression or statement`

`Unexpected token '-a' in expression or statement`

If the paths do not have spaces, it works without issue:

`C:\Temp\Autoruns\autorunsc64.exe -accepteula -a * > C:\Temp\Autoruns\output.txt`

How can I type this up to work with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Autoruns\autorunsc64.exe -a * > C:\Program Files (x86)\Autoruns\output.txt` so it can run from these locations using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very common question.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Autoruns\autorunsc64.exe"
```

Or even

```
C":\Program Files (x86)\Autoruns\autorunsc64.exe"
```

I would just add it to the path.